# SQL Query to retrieve non distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume the data set contains 3 Columns and n number of rows

```
{Table - ProductSales
 Customer Name    Transaction no   Productlist
     A                 T1              P1
     A                 T2              P2
     B                 T3              P3
     C                 T4              P4
     D                 T5              P5
     D                 T6              P6
     }
{Consider the sales table : Sales
  TransNo       Amount of Sales Quantity
    T1              $100           4
    T2              $200           2
    T3              $50            1
    T4              $500           10
    T5              $600           3
    T6              $700           4}
```

Now I want to retrieve the Customer records which has more than one transaction 
records .Expected output:

```
     A                 T1              P1     
     A                 T2              P2     
     D                 T5              P5     
     D                 T6              P6
```

& also another set I need to get overall sales report:Expectedoutput

```
{Customer     NumberofTransaction     totalsales totalquantitypurchased
     A              2                    $300             6
     B              1                    $50              1
     C              1                    $500             10
     D              2                    $1300             7}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add a tag for the RDBMS you're using: MySQL, SQL-SERVER, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of SQL (including SQL Server) support the ANSI standard window functions.  With these, you can do:

```
select CustomerName, TransactionNum, Productlist
from (select ps.*, count(*) over (partition by CustomerName) as cnt
      from ProductSales ps
     ) ps
where cnt > 1;
```

If your version of SQL doesn't support window functions, you can do something similar with aggregation and a join/in/exists clause.

Answer (score 1):

For your first part refer to Gordon's reply and for 2nd part

```
select CustomerName, COUNT(sl.TransactionNo), SUM(AmountOfSales), SUM(Quantity)
from ProductSales ps
JOIN Sales sl
ON ps.TransactionNo = sl.TransactionNo
GROUP BY CustomerName
```